# How to run versioned images of docker with nexus?

Tags: docker, nexus

I am currently generating images of docker and upload them to Nexus Repository Manager, but always the same image: latest image, I would like to have a versioned of images. What dou you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
docker build -t name:version
```

Answer (score 1):

The versions you are refering to are Docker tags.

This can be done in two ways:

```
docker build -t username/image_name:tag_name .
```

or

```
docker tag SOURCE_IMAGE[:TAG] TARGET_IMAGE[:TAG]
```